# Joomla 3 frontend view xml: How do I add a custom field to the menu item's paramaters?

Tags: menu-item, menu, view, front-end, menu-parameters

I have frontend views on a custom component.  When I add a menu item for that view, I want a tab with custom paramaters.  The field type will be sql.

This is what I have thus far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
        <layout title="Site Route Link" hidden="false">
                <message>A menu link to a route created in the backend.</message>
        </layout>
        <fields name="Route Settings">
            <fieldset name="Route Settings">
                <field name="route_id" type="sql" label="Select a route" description="Select a route previously created in the backend." query="SELECT id AS value, route_name AS route_id FROM #__cddir_routes where id_type = 1"/>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
</metadata>
```

The tab is created in the menu item, but it is empty.  (This is when creating the menu item) Can you perhaps see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Jacques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the blank spaces in *fields name* and *fieldset name* attributes

```
<fields name="RouteSettings">
   <fieldset name="RouteSettings">
        <field name="route_id" type="sql" label="Select a route" description="Select a route previously created in the backend." query="SELECT id AS value, route_name AS route_id FROM #__cddir_routes where id_type = 1"/>
   </fieldset>
</fields>
```